# What will go in the field 'Deauthorize Callback URL' and 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' to enable facebook login on ezpublish?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, uri, ezpublish

I am using ezPublish version 4.3 and trying to integrate Facebook login for all users in the system. I followed the instructions at [Facebook Login for ezPublish](http://blog.nxcgroup.com/2012/ez-publish-social-networks-integration-signin/#.Vgr2HZfdbHs)

However, it requires me to configure two values in Facebook app of mine i.e. *Deauthorize Callback URL* and *Valid OAuth redirect URIs*. I am not sure what is the *OAuth URI* format used in ezPublish for login/ failed login. Please suggest the solution.

Comment: do you mean logout/login URL ?